# Bad calculation with multiple left join and count (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, laravel, database

I have 3 tables in my database (users, payments and customers), what I want is to get all the new customers (of such date range) of a user and the sum of all payments (of such date range ). But the calculation is wrong, it only works fine if I remove the left join of customers, but I need to count the new customers, below the tables and my attempt:

**Table users:**

id | name

**Table payments**

id | users_id | price | date ....

**Table customers**

id | users_id | name | cuil | created_at ....

**My try:**

```
$query = Payment::query();
->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.users_id')
->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.users_id', '=', 'payments.users_id')
->whereBetween('payments.date', [$request->value1 . " 00:00:00",$request->value5 . " 11:59:59"])
->whereBetween('customers.created_at', [$request->value1 . " 00:00:00",$request->value5 . " 11:59:59"])
->select(\DB::raw('SUM(payments.price) as total, count(customers.id) as total_customers))
->groupBy('payments.users_id');
return $query->paginate(env('ITEMS_PER_PAGE', 10));
```

As a result I need the sum of clients in such date range and the sum of payments of such date range, but grouped by users. However, the calculation is wrong ...

Comment: How is the calculation wrong? Can you provide sample input, sample (incorrect) output and the expectations of what may a correct output be?

Comment: shouldn't the right side time be 23:59:59?

Comment: I also want to know why are you always trying left join? because you want ALL the payments wether there is users/customers or not?

Comment: @Psycho I can only guess, but maybe it's possible that a payment is linked to a user without an existing customer account.

Answer (score 0):

`>whereBetween('customers.created_at', [$request->value1 . " 00:00:00",$request->value5 . " 11:59:59"])`

seems to be incorrect, because you are checking whether the customer was created in the time interval of the payment that you have specified. However, it is quite possible that the customer already existed due to earlier payments and paid for some new products/services in the searched interval. It seems that this line should be removed.

If there could be more than one customer having the same `user_id`, then you will get duplicates into the results before you group them and you will count the different customers. A possible fix:

```
$query = Payment::query();
->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.users_id')
->leftJoin('customers', 'customers.users_id', '=', 'payments.users_id')
->whereBetween('payments.date', [$request->value1 . " 00:00:00",$request->value5 . " 23:59:59"])
->select(\DB::raw('SUM(payments.price) as total, count(customers.id) as total_customers))
->groupBy('payments.users_id');
return $query->paginate(env('ITEMS_PER_PAGE', 10));
```

If multiple customers are possible for the same user, then you will need to polish the approach above further.

Comment: shouldn't the right side time be 23:59:59?

Comment: Removing that increases the calculations and customers created in that date range.

Comment: @Psycho the right side time is 23:59:59 in my answer. The first code is only a quote from the question, pointing out that the given line is unnecessary.

Comment: opps my bad, somehow missed my eye :'(

Comment: @Psycho no worries, I've missed that initially as well and then seen your excellent comment to the question...